# How can I get Symfony log dir from the controller?

Tags: php, symfony

How can I get current log file on a Symfony's controller ?

I know I could do it this way:

```
$logFile = $this->container->getParameter('kernel.root_dir') . "/logs/" . 
               $this->container->get('kernel')->getEnvironment() . ".log";
```

but this fails if the log dir is customized. So I thought there should be a more direct way of getting it. Is there is some parameter that holds the current log file ?

A related question: where can I get the list of all container parameters ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For a list of parameters, use the symfony console:

For symfony 2.6 ( maybe 2.7)

```
app/console debug:container --parameters
```

For 2.3

```
app/console container:debug --parameters
```

EDIT FOR THE LOG DIR

The log dir is stored in kernel parameters. You can access like this:

```
$container->get('kernel')->getLogDir();
```

Comment: Well that was really useful. Now I have all the parameters and know where the logs are in case of customization. But still none points directly to the file being used. Do you know of any way to get the information on which file is being used directly from symfony, without using concatenation ?

Comment: The "file being used" depends on the monolog channel, and the environment, so you will not be able to guess it with any parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For Sf. 2.6: (console dir was moved)

```
 bin/console debug:container --parameters
```